# How to unbind a bind event in jquery / javascript?

Tags: jquery, bind

I have an event attached to a DIV on `mousemove`:

```
 $('#graph-container').bind('mousemove', function(){ 
     // something happens here
 }
```

How do I unbind it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's **well worth your time** to spend an hour or two reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and it pays you back almost immediately in saved time.

Comment: This thred could be read by anyone ... and sometimes happens some mind blocks that you forget simple things ... and finding answer this way trough google really helps ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind), e.g.:

```
$('#graph-container').unbind('mousemove');
```

That example will remove **all** jQuery-attached `mousemove` handlers from the element. You can remove only specific ones by using the same function reference you used with `bidn`, or using jQuery's event "namespaces," [more in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Note that in any vaguely-modern version of jQuery, the more up-to-date API calls are [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off).